# why the fetch method doesn't work on my svelte program?

Tags: fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to recover data from my tmdb api on svelte . So I used fetch in a load function that I exported and console.log the result as a json but my console doesn't return anything. anyone have an explanation and if possible a solution to this?

```
<script context='module'>
   export async function load({fetch}){
    const res = await fetch(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/65334?language=fr-FR'
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    if(res.ok===true){
        return{
            props:{miraculous:data.results}
        }
    };
   }
   
</script>
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling it? Load functions don't work like that anymore, see [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load).

Comment: you are likely following an outdated tutorial, this has changed around september 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to [H.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) for your help. thanks to you and the documentation i found it :

this for a +page.js:

```
 <script>
 /** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
 export async function load({fetch}) {
 const res = await fetch(
     'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/65334?language=fr-FR'
 );
 const r = await res.json();
 return{r}
 }
 </script>
```

And this for +page.svelte in script:

```
<script>
/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
export let data;
console.log(data)
</script>
```